# Tauri fleet location

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Where are the BC-303 and BC-304 constructed? I know in Season 6 Episode  11 the female news person is taken to a desert location and takes a tour of the BC-303. Is the location ever stated where they are built like at Area 51?

Comment: Area 51 probably makes the most sense as a location notorious for housing all sorts of military secrets, and figures on-screen multiple times as a safe-keeping site and R&D center for advanced and alien technology.

Comment: i thought so too especially when Nevada was mentioned in the episode I re-watched tonight.

Comment: *JULIA: "You mean it could explode." JONAS: "With enough force to turn the entire **state of Nevada** into a smoking crater, yes.".* There's no specific mention of Area 51. The [episode transcript](https://imsdb.com/transcripts/Stargate-SG1-Prometheus.html) certainly thinks so, but I can't see lick of evidence for it.